# BiSection Java test inputs

Tags: java, bisection

I have this code to analyse. It's the bisection method.

What are the inputs which will result in going to the branch of line 18 and 19?

```
public class BiSectionExample {
    public double root(double d, double e, double f) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        double middle;
        if (d >= e) {
            System.out.println("1");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("low must be lower than high");
        }

        System.out.println(d + " " + e + " " + f);
        while (e - d > f) {
            System.out.println("2");
            System.out.println("once");
            middle = (e + d) / 2;
            if (middle < e) {
                System.out.println("3");
                d = middle;
            } else {
                System.out.println("4"); // line 18
                e = middle; // line 19
            }
        }

        System.out.println((e + d) / 2);
        return (e + d) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use the likes of JUnit to carryout an array of tests to see what inputs cause for that result... It may *even* be worth looking into jacoco, this way you can see that your unit tests have successfully covered all branches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes im using jUnit to test it. I just need to ensure that statement is reached but unsure of the inputs required.

Comment: In that case it may be worth you using an IDE with a debugger to help you understand how that statement gets reached, I'm not sure what else I can advise. After all, it reaches that statement due to the business logic that you've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JUnit to test it you could use a repeated test and input randomly generated values so the probability to reach the lines is high. Also it would be usefull to set a debugger break point to the lines so you see what was the input when reaching the lines.

But by going through the test manually I think that it's not possible to end in this case, because:

- `middle` is the middle between `e` and `d`
- for `middle` to be greater than `e` (the else case) `d` would need to be greater than `e`
- this case seems to be not allowed because of the first if-clause (which throws an exception in this case)

It might be possible if `e` and `d` are the same value (so `middle` is equal to `e` and not smaler) but this could also fail because of the double precision.